# What are some reliable and free basic online nutrition courses?

Tags: nutrition

I took several human-nutrition-focused courses in my past education, and I'd like to provide a corpus of resources covering fundamental human nutritional information, as, for example, what are calories/carbohydrates, or how are different fats used by the body, or proper hydration, etc.

Basic stuff for a smart consumer (domestic or wild) to make the right nutritional food choices. I've seen a lot of OCW and slideshows for the topic, but nothing that's quite right vis-a-vis covering the core ideas. Just wanted to ask [in the spirit of this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free) what this community has found that does the topic justice, so I can share with others.

Answer (score 4):

Good question, and this is not a complete answer, as I cannot think specifically of a *free course*.  I will update this if I find one.  But a very good resource that I feel provides a great foundation for what balanced nutrition is, with a lot of good explanations (that you don't have to be a scientist to understand), is a Harvard public health website. One of the primary researchers involved did a Skype lecture with us, during which he presented the research behind their information, and we felt it was quite solid: 
https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/healthy-eating-plate/

Comment: I know about this. This is good.

Answer (score 1):

The best directory of online courses that I know of is class-central.com. It includes and compares edx.org and Coursera. The more general subject ["Nutrition & Wellness"](https://www.class-central.com/subject/nutrition-and-wellness?sort=rating-up) lists 99 courses. Only a few will fit all of your requirements. I have not tried them but they are often university backed and from other subjects I know class-central's rating system is useful.

Comment: You can't attest to their quality, then why post?

Answer (score 0):

There are several online learning platforms that offer free and/or paid courses (in some platforms the courses are usually free of charge, and you can pay to get an official completion certificate). Personally, I have used so far only [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) (which is completely free to use and does not offer graduation certificates)  and [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) (which offers the material for free, but the certificate is paid), but I did not see that they offer such a course.

However, [edx.org](https://www.edx.org/), with which I have had no experience, seems to offer a course that might be suitable for your needs (free to use, pay for a certificate, according to the course webpage). Check it out [here](https://www.edx.org/course/nutrition-health-micronutrients-wageningenx-nutr102x).

There may be other online learning platforms as well. If you haven't done that already, browse through [this Google search](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=online%20nutrition%20courses&oq=online%20nutrition%20courses&gs_l=psy-ab.3...422479.423318.0.423558.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.Xf-Qg0urrpg).

Edit: come to think of it, [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/food-and-health) by Coursera may also be of use to you (see the syllabus for more details).